# Unit-tests in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I need to organise the launch Unit-Tests in MS Test Manager. Can It be done? I create controller but I can't specify path for my solution or tests dll.

I'm not sure that launch Unit-Tests in Microsoft test manager are possible, but my boss requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should probably do is setup your build server to run the tests. Then use test manager to trigger a build, which will in turn run the tests.

There's not much value in running the tests again on previously built code as it won't have changed. The tests should run on the code as it builds and then again when the code changes and is consequently rebuilt.